# angular webpack ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to get ng-file-upload to work with my angularjs project, which uses webpack. I installed ng-file-upload via npm and added it to my main app.js

```
var ngFileUpload = require('../../node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload.min');
module.exports = angular.module('app', [ngFileUpload])
```

But I'm still getting:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, since I tried to find any information about this with no success.

Comment: Which version of angular? Why do you use require? Can you post you index.html?

Comment: It's angular 1.5.6. My whole app is using require for modules, because it's an angular webpack and it does not contain index.html where scripts are included.

Comment: shouldn't it be angular.module('app', ['ngFileUpload']) with the quotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for what ngFileUpload is exporting and what's the name of module. Right now you are injecting the module inside angular dependency but you need to just give name of your ngFileUpload module not the ngFileUpload it self. That's why you are getting this error. It's expecting a name of module but getting a object instead.

Comment: You're right, changing to `require('ng-file-upload')` solved problem :)